# cannot redirect stdin in bash

Tags: bash, stdin, file-descriptor

I am playing with file descriptors. A common practice is to redirect stdout and stderr using file descriptors, like this:

```
$ ls >files.txt 2>errors.txt
```

another example might be:

```
$ echo 'Hello there' > message.txt 2> errors.txt
```

however the following does not work:

```
$ echo 'Hello There' 0> input_message.txt > output_message.txt 2> errors.txt
```

It seems like the file descriptor 0 is not working as `input_message.txt` is empty, I'd expect to find the text message `Hello There` instead.

Why is that ?

Comment: `0` is `stdin`. What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I'd like to have input text (i.e. Hello there) in a file, BUT I wanna do this on the fly, that's why I'm passing a stdin and not a file.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by on the fly ? Do you have an example ?

Comment: @Harry `Hello there` is an argument, it is passed to `echo` through an `execve` call, not stdin.

Comment: @oguzismail can you clarify the difference between execve call, stdin and arguments ? thanks

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46372/whats-the-difference-between-stdin-and-arguments-passed-to-command

Comment: @HarryC. `echo` does not read from stdin. Further, redirecting stdin (fortunately) does not *create* a file, it assumes that the file is already present.

Answer (score 2):

You use `<` (or `0<`) to redirect stdin, like:

```
command <file
```

or:

```
command <&fd
```

where `fd` is a file descriptor opened for reading.

As for your example, since `echo` ignores stdin, this correction won't change the behavior.

See [Bash Reference Manual § 3.6 Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).